# Set a layoutmargin on a dynamically created checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout, android-checkbox

I'm writing a task manager app that downloads a list of tasks and subtasks from a server and creates a new checkbox for each item and adds it to a linear layout (called ll below). The problem I'm having is that I cannot set the "layout margin left" using java like I can with XML (this is for the subtasks to indent them a bit on the screen). I can set most other xml properties, but cb.setMargins() doesn't work (says undefined for type checkbox). Setting the padding of course does not achieve the desired result.

```
for(int i=0;i<tasks.size();i++) {
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
cb.setText(tasks.get(i).subtask_desc);
cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_xml);
ll.addView(cb);
    }
```

Any ideas or how I would work through this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you should add the checkbox to the LinearLayout using the correct LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = 123;
li.addView(cb, params);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've seen that code 100 times just never realized how to use it properly. I always thought that created a new linear layout. This worked perfectly and was very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try this...

```
    private LinearLayyout ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = 123;;
    CheckBox cb;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(categoryListArray[i]);
        ll.addView(cb, ll);
    }
```

Comment: How does this add a margin on a dynamically created checkbox?